# NOT NULL constraint failed on temporary table that doesn't exists

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

I am building something with nodejs nestjs typeorm and use sqlite for storage. Everything did work fine but now I wanted to add a column to a table that is not null.

I added the column to the entity file and let nestjs generate that column for me but I get the error message `QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: temporary_MyTable.deleted`. (Note: the table name is `MyTable`, I don't know where the 'temporary' comes from)

So I did delete every entry in that table and run the program again and after that the column was generated. I did safe a few rows via the program to the table and looked into the DB and saw that my new column does have data in it.

But now comes the strange part. When restarting the program now, it won't start and will also give me the error message: `QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: temporary_MyTable.deleted`. When looking into the DB now, all data fields of `deleted` are now `null` after the program tryed to start. I don't write any data to the DB at the program start...

So the next thing I tryed was to delete the whole DB and let nestjs generate it from scratch. This did work for the first start and I wrote some data to that table. After a restart I will still get the `QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: temporary_MyTable.deleted` error message but this time the column is not `null` but still contains the right data.

What is wrong with that table? What am I missing?

```
  @Column({ select: false })
  deleted: boolean;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to add a NOT NULL constraint to a column that already has data in it. SQLite does not allow this, because it would require changing all of the existing rows to have a value for the column.

To fix this, you need to either:

- Delete all of the data from the table before adding the NOT NULL
  constraint.
- Change the column to be nullable.

Incase, you want to delete all the data in the table:

```sql
DELETE FROM MyTable;
```

Then Run:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN deleted boolean NOT NULL;
```

Or Else, make a Temporary Table to secure all the data then change the table column to not null with default statement, then copy that data into the table.